# How to get block id on block add & edit form?

Tags: 8, blocks

Blocks are plugin in Drupal-8, I need to add a form element in the block add form & all the block edit forms. 
I am able to add the new form element in the form by form alter. But i need to get the block id on submit(custom submit handler). For block add forms block id has to be new block created & for block edit form, the existing block id.

How can i get the block id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a lookt at [Extend Block Class](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204818/extend-block-class) and my answer there about the block_class module.

It does exactly the same to add configurable CSS classes to blocks.

Comment: Block class is allowing to add classes to all the existing block, but it is not adding class field to new custom block plugins. I also need to display my form element while adding as well as editing custom blocks.

Comment: It supports those too. Creating custom blocks is a two-step process, you first create the block and then put it in a region, on that step you can also configure the same settings as with all other blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Place this cistom block(php code) to seven theme under Breadcrumbs for page /admin/structure/block/manage/*

```
<?php
/**
* Cistom admin block for get number block numberID on edit entity.block.edit_form
*/
if( \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.block.edit_form' ) {
    $blockMachineName = \Drupal::token()->replace('[current-page:url:args:last]');
    $blockLoad = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($blockMachineName); //dump($blockLoad);
    if($blockLoad) { //dump($blockLoad->get('id'));
        $blockIdStr = str_ireplace('block_content:', '', $blockLoad->get('settings')['id']); //print "blockIdStr: {$blockIdStr}";
        $query = \Drupal::database()->select('block_content', 'bc')->fields('bc', ['id'])->condition('bc.uuid', $blockIdStr);
        $blockIdNum = $result = $query->execute()->fetchField(); //print " blockIdNum: {$blockIdNum}"; //drupal_set_message("id: {$blockIdNum}");
        print "<b>BlockIDs</b> Str: {$blockIdStr} Num: {$blockIdNum}";
    }
}
?>
```